# SQL Get highest repeating value for a group clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a SQL query which should tell me that for each ID which value repeated most of time. 
For example lets take the following table:

```
Id  Value
1   10
1   20
1   10
1   10
2   1
1   3
```

Desired Output

```
Id  Value   Count
1   10      3
2   1       1
```

From above example, it shows that for Id 1, Value 10 was repeated most of times and for Id 2, value 1 was repeated most of times
Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rank` to number the id's based on their value counts in descending order and pick up the 1st ranked rows.

```
select id, value, cnt
from (select id, value, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (partition by id order by count(*) desc) as rnk
      from t
      group by id, value) x 
where rnk = 1
```

Based on Gordon's comment, if you need only one value per id in case of ties, use `row_number` instead of `rank`, as `rank` returns all the ties in value counts.

Comment: As a note:  `rank()` will return multiple rows for the same `id` if there are ties.  If you want to guarantee only one row for each `id`, then use `row_number()` instead.